# How to get the value of selected Date Time Range from html to ts file in angular?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am trying to select a From Date To Date Range in html and get the value in ts file. I am using `[owlDateTimeTrigger]` module. I am not sure of how to return the selected date range.

Following is the html code I used.

```html
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="example-wrapper">                                                              
<label class="example-input-wrapper">   
<label>
Date Time Range:
<input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" [owlDateTime]="dt1"
[selectMode]="'range'">
<owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time (keyup)="dateRange(dt1)" >
</label>
</label>                                               
</div>                                       
</div>
```

and in my .ts file,

```
public dateTime: any;


dateRange(dateTime)
{
  console.log("This is the DATE:" + dateTime);
}
```

I am getting the output like `This is the DATE: undefined`. What needs to be changed for getting exact datetime selected?

Answer (score 0):

use ngModel

```
<input [(ngModel)]="dateTimeRange" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" [owlDateTime]="dt1"
[selectMode]="'range'">
<owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>

value is {{dateTimeRange}}
```

declare in .ts

```
public dateTimeRange: any;
```

Comment: I am just getting null value in `value is {{dateTimeRange}}`. Any method should be called from html to ts file?

Comment: Are you getting null ,After selecting the date range ?

Comment: Yes. Nothing displays after selecting the Date range.  Also, how can i pass it to the ts file?

Comment: take reference from this https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-datetimepicker?file=src%2Fapp%2Frange%2Frange.component.html